# tqdm failure with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, tqdm

`tqdm` is one of my favorite Python packages, but I have an annoying issue with it and trying to figure out if this is my fault or not.

While running a loop with `tqdm` using `Jupyter Notebook` and encoutering a `RunTime Error` the recovery is really hard - fixing the bug and reruning the loop ofter result in **multiline** prints, instead of `tqdm` original **single line**. The only way to get back is to **restart the Kernel** which is not very useful.

Are the any other solutions?

I can't reproduce the issue intentionally but here is an example code that might cause it:

```
from tqdm import trange
s=0
for i in trange(100):
    s+=i
    if i==10:
        raise ValueError
```

and then reruning the cell.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm seeing a similar issue whenever I interrupt a cell (effectively `KeyboardInterrupt`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome this issue, I use the following conditional `import` which works in code that might run in Jupyter Notebook *or* in the console (and do nothing if not run interactively):

```
# progress.py
import sys


def tqdm(iterable, **kwargs):
    """Fake progress function."""

    return iterable


# check if running notebook and use notebook backend for tqdm progress bar
if 'IPython' in sys.modules:

    from IPython import get_ipython
    from IPython.display import display_javascript, Javascript

    from tqdm import tqdm

    ip = get_ipython()

    if 'IPKernelApp' in ip.config:
        monkey_patch = f"""
            from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
            import {__name__} as module
            module.tqdm = tqdm
        """
        monkey_patch = ';'.join(x.strip() for x in monkey_patch.strip().split('\n'))
        display_javascript(Javascript(f"""IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("{monkey_patch}");"""))
```

Then use it:

```
$ jupyter console  # or ipython3
In [1]: import progress

In [2]: list(progress.tqdm(range(10)))
100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:00<00:00, 120873.31it/s]
Out[2]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```